# Menu is not hidden on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the following link:

[Link](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/CheckSite/ms_radiology.html)

Whenever user visits, in IE or FF, the menu first is shown expanded for a few seconds and then collapsed. Can anyone tell me where I have to edit to ensure it's not expanded on page load. Only happens to certain pages.

**EDIT**: i did the following and it's fine now.

```
#topMainNav .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px; /* padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none; /* <<-- **ADDED THIS AND IT SOLVED THE PROBLEM** */
}
```

Comment: didn't recognize the issue on both the browser.

Comment: Which menu? Ones classed `.dropdown`?

Comment: It's sporadic. if you click on few different links, the navigation menu will show up as expanded for a quick second. let me know if you are able to see it or if i should post a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<div class="expand" style="display: none">
```

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce behaviour, but you could try this:

```
        <head>
           {....}
           <style id="substyle">.dropdown{display:none !important}</style>
        </head>
```

and then use preferably onload than jquery ready event callback function: (coz triggered after)

```
window.onload = function() {$('#substyle').remove();}
```

Comment: It's sporadic. if you click on few different links, the navigation menu will show up as expanded for a quick second. let me know if you are able to see it or if i should post a screenshot